# POST array of objects in Alamofire POST method - Swift/IOS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire to post an array of multiple objects, which look like this:

```
class Person {

dynamic var firstName: String?
dynamic var lastName: String?
dynamic var email: String?
dynamic var state: String?

init(){}
init(firstName:String, lastName:String, email:String){
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.email = email
} }
```

I have created an array of Persons and added it to the dictionary like this:

```
let zipCode = “20876”
    let city = “Rockville”
    let persons = [Person]()
    let state = “MD”

    let params: [String:AnyObject] = [
        “zipCode” : zipCode!,
        “city” : city!,
        “persons”: NSArray(array: persons),
        “state” : state!

    ]
```

And then tried to send it to a web service and I am getting an error message saying: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write’

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON {(req, res, json, error) in }
```

Did anyone try posting an array, is alamofire capable of doing so? 
I hope i made question clear. Sorry if this is too simple of a question to answer, i spent my whole day figuring this out, but didn't work out. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create dictionary from person class object that object is not serilizable

```
class Person {

    dynamic var firstName: String?
    dynamic var lastName: String?
    dynamic var email: String?
    dynamic var state: String?

    init(){}
    init(firstName:String, lastName:String, email:String){
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.email = email
    }
    func getDictFormat() -> [String: String]{

        return ["firstName" : firstName!, "lastName" : lastName!, "email" : email!, "state" : state!]
    }
}
```

Comment: And what would be the next step? Thank you

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I have created a new dictionary of dictionaries and used the function to append each Persons dictionary in a for loop. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wenderlich has its recent tutorials on Alamofire .

Please refer Links :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial
 (See Creating a Request Router)
http://www.raywenderlich.com/87595/intermediate-alamofire-tutorial